# Endomorphism on $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ be a surjective morphism and $D$ be a reduced divisor satisfying ${f^{-1}(D)}_{\text{red}}=D$. Is $f$ unramified outside $D$ ?

Answer (score 5):

No. Take for instance
$$
f(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_0^d,x_1^d,\dots,x_n^d)
$$
and $D = \{x_0 = 0\}$.